# Split declaration and initialisation in class, C++

Tags: c++, initialization, declaration

I started out with a piece of code that both declares and initialises two objects from 3rd party libraries in one line (see below). That worked just fine.

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

const int gpioPin = 0;
OneWire oneWire(gpioPin);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);
```

I then wanted to wrap it in a class and initialise `oneWire` and `sensors` when the class is initialised. So I came up with this:

```
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

class TemperatureSensor
{
private:
  OneWire oneWire;
  DallasTemperature sensors;

public:
  TemperatureSensor(int gpioPin);
};

TemperatureSensor::TemperatureSensor(int gpioPin)
{
  oneWire(gpioPin);
  sensors(&oneWire);
}
```

Which throws the error `call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type`. So I guess I can't initialise an object like that when the declaration is already made. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor

Comment: You can only call the constructor directly, if you're using a initializer list (`TemperatureSensor::TemperatureSensor(int gpioPin) : oneWire(gpioPin), sensors(&oneWire) {}`). Once the constructor body is entered, all member variables of class type have been constructed (in this case using the default constructor. I hope there's a move or copy assignment opertor for those types, so that you can do `TemperatureSensor::TemperatureSensor(int gpioPin) { oneWire = OneWire(gpioPin); sensors = DallasTemperature(&oneWire); }`...

Comment: `sensors(&oneWire);` means `sensor.operator()(&oneWire);`. It does not mean construct `sensor`.

Comment: Thanks, the initialiser list got me going in the right direction!